# Finding the longest substring in alphabetical order from a given string

Tags: python, sorting, alphabetical

Ive been working on a question to find the longest substring in alphabetical order from a given string. I have a lot of experience in C++ but am absolutely new to python. Ive written this code

```
s = raw_input("Enter a sentence:")

a=0   #start int
b=0   #end integer
l=0   #length
i=0

for i in range(len(s)-1):
    j=i
    if j!=len(s)-1:
    while s[j]<=s[j+1]:
        j+=1
    if j-i>l:  #length of current longest substring is greater than stored substring
        l=j-i
        a=i
        b=j

print 'Longest alphabetical string is ',s[i:j]
```

But I keep on getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/python/alphabetical.py", line 13, in <module>
    while s[j]<=s[j+1]:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

What am I doing wrong here? Again, I am very new to python!

Comment: What if the string is empty?

Comment: I think your last line should have `s[a:b]` instead of `s[i:j]`.

Comment: Do *not* use single letter variables. In your code you even had to add comments in order to let us understand it! Simply use `a -> start_index`, `b -> end_index`, `l -> length`[BTW *never* use lowercase `L`. in many fonts it is too similar to a `1`]. `i` and `j` are acceptable because they are standard names for indexes.

Comment: If you are new to python I would highly recommend visualise python website. It allows you to see the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while s[j]<=s[j+1]:
    j+=1
```

Can run off the end of the string.

Try:

```
while j!=len(s)-1 and s[j]<=s[j+1]:
    j+=1
```

Also think about what it means when you find the end of a sequence that's alphabetical - is there any reason to check for a longer sequence starting at some position later within that sequence?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple piece of code to achieve what you want

```
s = 'kkocswzjfq'
char = ''
temp = ''
found = ''
for letter in s:
    if letter >= char:
        temp += letter
    else:
        temp = letter
    if len(temp) > len(found):
        found = temp
    char = letter
print(found)
```