# first time programming-exercise

Tags: python, string, substring

First time programming ever... I'm trying to do this exercise to.. :

Write a program that prints the longest substring of s in which the letters occur in alphabetical order. For example, if s = 'azcbobobegghakl', then your program should print

Longest substring in alphabetical order is: beggh

I was here..before starting to freak out:

```
s = 'abcdezcbobobegghakl'
n = len(s) 
x = 0


x += 1
lengh = s[x-1]
if s[x] >= s[x-1]:
    lengh = lengh + s[x]


if s[x+1] < s[x]:
    n = len(lengh)
if x > n:
    break 

print('Longest substring in alphabetical order is: ' + str(lengh))
```

I know this code is bad..I m trying to find substring in alphabetical order and is some way keep the longest one! I know could be normal, because I never programmed before but i feel really frustrated...any good idea/help??

Comment: What programming language do you use? I can't recognize it.

Comment: What language are you programming in? And have you learned about loops? They would help here

Comment: i have the sensation that i m not going nowhere with this approach..any idea?

Comment: I learned -for in loop- and -while loop-....so far..so i m trying to do it with that..

Comment: When beginning programming, first thing you should do is to think about the problem.  How would you solve this problem in human language terms?

Comment: Same question asked thrice in two days. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19604825/finding-the-longest-substring-in-alphabetical-order-from-a-given-string, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581585/longest-substring-in-alphabetical-order, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601903/find-the-longest-substring-in-alphabetical-order

Comment: i wrote down my idea on paper before to start:

i would like to analyze all the string letter by letter, when the next letter is increasing i concatenate, when the letter is smaller (not in alphabetic older) i stop
and i store the result.

I start again with the letter that interrupt the loop, and I find another possible sequence and I store it.

At the end I compare the results and I keep the longest one.

am I totally wrong here?? thanks for the patience

Comment: @nico: do yourself a favor and learn the language properly: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/ :)

Comment: @Erik Allik that's the reason because I'm taking classes.. thanks anyhow

Comment: @nico: OK, undestood; but it's always better to use a good book to learn the thing on your own rather than going at the slow pace in the rather inefficient lessons.

Comment: @nico I wish I had Python and Stackoverflow when I learned programming :) Good luck!

Comment: @thefourtheye you missed out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19562340/comparing-characters-in-a-string-sequentially-in-python

Comment: @nico What you're doing here is against edx honor code. It's just unfair to other participants who work hard. Anyway, it's not the first exercise and **if** you **really** followed the course videos and finger exercises you would have known how to do it yourself. -1.

Answer (score 0):

First try to decompose your problem into little problems (do not optimize ! until your problem is solved), if you have learned about functions they are a good way to decompose execution flow into readable and understandable snippets.

An example to start would be :

```
def get_sequence_size(my_string, start):
   # Your code here
   return size_of_sequence

current_position = 0
while current_position < len(my_string):
   # Your code here using get_sequence_size() function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_longest_substr(my_str):

    # string var to hold the result
    res = ""

    # candidate for the longest sub-string 
    candidate = ""

    # for each char in string
    for char in my_str:

        # if candidate is empty, just add the first char to it
        if not candidate:
            candidate += char

        # if last char in candidate is "lower" than equal to current char, add char to candidate
        elif candidate[-1] <= char:
            candidate += char

        # if candidate is longer than result, we found new longest sub-string
        elif len(candidate) > len(res):
            res= candidate
            candidate = char

        # reset candidate and add current char to it
        else:
            candidate = char

    # last candidate is the longest, update result
    if len(candidate) > len(res):
        res= candidate

    return res


def main():
    str1 = "azcbobobegghaklbeggh"
    longest = find_longest_substr(str1)
    print longest


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Neat code. However it doesn't return the correct result when the longest substring is at the start or at the end of the string. Also,  slicing with `[-1:]` is a little redundant and you can simply use `[-1]`.

Comment: correct. good observation. haven't thought this all the way through. Just wanted to give a jump start for nico. Thanks for guys like you, we keep this community reliable.

Answer (score 0):

The following code solves the problem using the `reduce` method:

```
solution = ''

def check(substr, char):
    global solution
    last_char = substr[-1]
    substr = (substr + char) if char >= last_char else char
    if len(substr) > len(solution):
        solution = substr
    return substr

def get_largest(s):
    global solution
    solution = ''
    reduce(check, list(s))
    return solution
```

Answer (score 0):

These are all assuming you have a string (s) and are needing to find the longest substring in alphabetical order.

Option A

```
test = s[0]      # seed with first letter in string s
best = ''        # empty var for keeping track of longest sequence  

for n in range(1, len(s)):    # have s[0] so compare to s[1]
    if len(test) > len(best):
        best = test
    if s[n] >= s[n-1]:
        test = test + s[n]    # add s[1] to s[0] if greater or equal
    else:                     # if not, do one of these options 
        test = s[n]

print "Longest substring in alphabetical order is:", best
```

Option B

```
maxSub, currentSub, previousChar = '', '', ''
for char in s:
    if char >= previousChar:
        currentSub = currentSub + char
        if len(currentSub) > len(maxSub):
            maxSub = currentSub
    else: currentSub = char
    previousChar = char
print maxSub
```

Option C

```
matches = []
current = [s[0]]
for index, character in enumerate(s[1:]):
    if character >= s[index]: current.append(character)
    else:
        matches.append(current)
        current = [character]
print "".join(max(matches, key=len))
```

Option D

```
def longest_ascending(s):
    matches = []
    current = [s[0]]
    for index, character in enumerate(s[1:]):
        if character >= s[index]:
            current.append(character)
        else:
            matches.append(current)
            current = [character]
    matches.append(current)
    return "".join(max(matches, key=len))
print(longest_ascending(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def longest(s):
    buff = ''
    longest = ''

    s += chr(255)
    for i in range(len(s)-1):
        buff += s[i]
        if not s[i] < s[i+1]:
            if len(buff) > len(longest):
                longest = buff
            buff = ''
    if len(buff) > len(longest):
        longest = buff

    return longest
```